# PDO - Shows only 1 result in Table, not all with same ID

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have at the moment 2 results in my MySQL Database with same `user_id` and I want echo all in my HTML `table` with `PDO`, but it shows everytime only 1 result, not all.

```
<?php
$querytest = "SELECT o.output_valu,
  p.amount,
  p.amount_all,
  p.order_id,
  p.datetime
FROM allusers a
INNER JOIN order_history o
  ON a.account_number = o.account_number
INNER JOIN paymentall p
  ON o.output_vl_id = p.output_vl_id
WHERE a.account_number = :account_num
ORDER BY p.datetime";
$statementtest = $conn->prepare($queryoutgo);
$statementtest->bindParam(':account_num', $account_num);
$statementtest->execute();
$test_result = $statementtest->fetchAll();
foreach ($test_result as $row) {
  $outputtest = $row['output_valu']; 
}    
?>   
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Test</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $outputtest; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

With `print_r($test_result);` it shows my 2 `results` in `array`, but why not with my code?
I worked always with `mysqli` not PDO in the past, maybe someone here can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `foreach` block you overwrite `$outputtest` every iteration. This means only the last result will be displayed. Depending on if you want to show each result on a separate row or if you want all the results together in one cell, you should either create the cells in the `foreach` or concatenate all the results together.

EDIT:
What I think you want is this:

```
$querytest = "SELECT o.output_valu, p.amount, p.amount_all, " .
             "p.order_id, p.datetime " .
             "FROM allusers a inner join order_history o " .
             "ON a.account_number = o.account_number " .
             "INNER JOIN paymentall p " .
             "ON o.output_vl_id = p.output_vl_id " .
             "WHERE a.account_number =:account_num " .
             "ORDER BY p.datetime ";
             $statementtest = $conn->prepare($queryoutgo);
             $statementtest->bindParam(':account_num', $account_num);
             $statementtest->execute();
             $test_result = $statementtest->fetchAll();

?>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Test</th>
  </tr>
  <?php foreach($test_result as $row) { ?>
    <tr><td><?= $row['output_valu']; ?></td></tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh yes thanks, if i make the echo in the `foreach` in display both addresses, then i must create the table within  `foreach` to display all in new line right?

Comment: Instead of writing `foreach($test_result as $row) { $outputtest = $row['output_valu']; }`, write something like this `$outputtest = ''; foreach ($test_result as $row) { $outputtest .= $row['output_valu']; }`. The .= will add a string to an already existing string. You can read more about concatenation here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: With :     `<td> 
<?php foreach($test_result as $row)
{
$outputtest = $row['output_valu']; 
echo $outputtest ;     
}    ?> </td>` the results are together in one line, how can i make it in new table line?

Comment: I've edited the answer to reflect what I think you want. Also, please don't edit comments containing a question, this will break the context of the answer. Just add a new comment.